# I can't create a working .jar from outside my .class directory

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I want to create a jar file. But I want to be able to create it from another directory. I can only seem to create working .jar files if I create it from the same directory that stores the *.class files. I made a simpler project to demonstrate my difficulty:

├── MANIFEST.MF
├── Test.java
├── classes
│   ├── Test.class

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
```

If I run this command from the /classes/ directory, I create Test.jar that works fine

```
jar -cfm Test.jar ../MANIFEST.MF *.class
```

However, if I use this command from the / directory,

```
jar -cfm Test.jar MANIFEST.MF classes/*.class
```

and I try to run the .jar file, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

What can I do to create a .jar file from a different directory than /classes/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-C` option, as explained by the manual:

> **-C dir** Temporarily changes directories to dir while processing the following inputfiles argument.  Multiple -C dir inputfiles sets are allowed.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> % jar uf foo.jar -C classes bar.class
> ```
>
> would change to the classes directory and add the bar.class from that directory to foo.jar